# Let$T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ be the operator given by...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ be the operator given by 
$$T(v)=\left[\begin{matrix}-3 & 1 & 2\\-4 & 1& 4\\0&0 &-1\end{matrix}\right]v$$ Determine whether $T$ is decomposable or indecomposable.

Comment: That doesn't map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, that maps $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. Thank you

Comment: What is a decomposable operator? Google did not help me...

Comment: Google did not me help either, decomposable is often referred to reducible

Comment: How about Cartan Matrices? :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_matrix Look under "Classification"

Comment: By this definition your matrix is decomposable, if we take $I=\{ 3\}$... Does it make sense?

Comment: what is decomposable?

Comment: But the problem asks for the operator to be dcomposable, not the matrix. At least  as I read it. An operator can have lots of matrix representations depending on the vector space basis... @Ludolila

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, right... So we need another definition of "decomposable"...:) Any ideas?

Comment: @Ludolila No idea, I wasn't saying you were wrong, even, just that the phrasing of the problem would be odd if you were right. Wouldn't be the first problem that was phrased oddly :)

Comment: I would take this definition [here](http://www.psi.toronto.edu/matrix/special.html). It's decomposable if its similar to lower block triangular matrix, where the similarity transform must be a permutation.

Comment: You live and you learn. By the way, I think that @Elmar Zander 's definition coincides with the one I found (according to this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html ). Nice... =)

Comment: @ElmarZander That's equivalent to the definition Ludilla linked to in the Cartan Matrices wikipedia.

Comment: I think that is up to the OP to have and eventually give *at the very least* the definitions of something he's asking about...

Comment: @DonAntonio, right, but since we are having so much fun fishing and speculating...

Comment: Hehe...Well, at least this seems to be something new.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right. Cartan matrix sounded to specialised to me, so I didn't look that up. However, the definition makes perfect sense for general matrices, e.g. in numerical linear algebra for block matrix solvers.

Comment: @Ludolila If we agree on that definition, then $T$ is decomposable with the permutation $(3,2,1)$.

Comment: @ElmarZander, right, but what about ThomasAndrews' comment? So, by this definition this matrix is decomposable, but not the operator? Because I think that we can change basis (for this given operator) and get an indecomposable matrix... Sounds right?...

Comment: I mean, we all agree that this *particular* matrix is decomposable?

Answer (score 1):

After a long and extremely educating discussion (above), we will use the following definition:

"A $n \times n$ matrix $A$  is *decomposable* if there exists a nonempty proper subset $I \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}$ such that $a_{ij}=0$ whenever $i\in I$ and $j \notin I$ ".

According to this definition, the matrix in question is decomposable, since we can take $I=\{3\}$, and indeed $a_{31}=a_{32}=0$ (for $2,3 \notin I$).

Note, though, that we answered the question of decomposability of the matrix, and not the operator...

Comment: Why did you decide to take I={3}?

Comment: Because $a_{31}=a_{32}=0$. So $i$ has to be $3$. Is that what you meant?